# Connect multiple docker containers (docker-compose) - front -> api -> solr

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I'd like to connect multiple docker containers. I have 3 services:

- solr storing documents and returning results for a query
- Flask backend querying solr
- React front-end requesting to flask backend to get solr results and display on the page using fetch

I'm able to create the backend to query solr and display results when putting the url in the browser. However, I'm not able to use that endpoint from the front-end code using fetch. I'm also able to query another backend endpoint, but it's just a dummy one, returning "hello world" - so I'm suspecting the problem is with connection between 3 containers (as backend is connecting to solr, but front-end cannot connect on top of it).

My docekr-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    api-service:
        build: api
        volumes:
            - ./api/:/backend
        environment:
            - FLASK_ENV=development
            - FLASK_APP=app.py
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        networks:
            - solr
        depends_on:
            - solr
        links:
            - solr
    front:
        build: front
        volumes:
            - ./front:/frontend
            - node-modules:/frontend/node_modules
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=development
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
            - api-service
        links:
            - api-service
            - solr
    solr:
        image: solr:8.5
        container_name: solr
        ports:
            - "8983:8983"
        networks:
            - solr
        command:
            - solr-precreate
            - gettingstarted
volumes:
    node-modules:

networks:
  solr:
```

My Flask code to connect to Solr:

```
BASE_PATH='http://solr:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=%2A:%2A'
@app.route('/myquery', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_query_solr():
    connection = urlopen("{}".format(BASE_PATH))
    response = simplejson.load(connection)

    return response
```

My js code hitting Flask endpoint:

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/myquery/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {console.log(result["response"]["docs"])},
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error,
          });
        }
      )
    }
```

I tried instead of localhost:5000/myquery to use api:5000/myquery or solr:5000/myquery, but neither works - I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED or 404 when I inspect element in the browser. I read a few threads here. I was able to fix my previous problem based on that (which was connecting between api and solr - i fixed it using links in docker-compose.yml), but now I'm stack on consuming that via front-end.

Comment: The browser application can never use the Docker-internal host names; in a development environment `http://localhost:5000/myquery` is the most likely URL.  Do you see a matching request in the Flask logs?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, when I try to query localhost:5000/myquery from React, I get "api-service_1  | 192.168.112.1 - - [05/Jan/2021 12:04:41] "GET /myquery/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -" in the logs. When I'm querying localhost:5000/hello (which is a dummy Flask endpoint that returns just "hello world", it works).

Comment: You have `@app.route('/myquery')` without a trailing `/`.  Does changing the route to have a trailing slash, or removing the slash from the end of your URL, make a difference?  If Flask is reporting that 404 error then all of the Docker-level wiring is correct.

Comment: That solved the issue! Thank you very much, @DavidMaze, I've been trying to solve this for hours...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by DavidMaze, this was down to not having training / in @app.route('/myquery') and having it in fetch("http://localhost:5000/myquery/"). Removing the training / from fetch helped.